# How can I show the record with the nearest future due date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an app that tracks invoices and the payments associated with those invoices, but have come across a problem.

An invoice can have many payments, and in the payments table I have the following columns: "amount_paid", "balance", "due_date".

What I am trying to do is show just the payment with the next upcoming "due_date" for each invoice.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the next payment by date for each invoice, like so;

```
Payment.where(invoice_id: 1).order(due_date: :desc).first
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get back to my computer.

Comment: This queried all payments instead of just the payments associated with the invoice. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Buddy, see the where clause, it only queries that payment with the corresponding invoice id, otherwise your relations are wrong.